# JDBC Sink connector throwing java.sql.BatchUpdateException

Tags: apache-kafka, teradata, apache-kafka-connect

I started a Sink JDBC some weeks ago. Everything was fine until the logs started to thow this error:

```
[2019-06-27 11:35:44,121] WARN Write of 500 records failed, remainingRetries=10 (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask:68)
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.10] [Error 1338] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while executing a PreparedStatement batch request. Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException.
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeBatchUpdateException(ErrorFactory.java:149)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeBatchUpdateException(ErrorFactory.java:138)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.executeBatchDMLArray(TDPreparedStatement.java:276)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.executeBatch(TDPreparedStatement.java:2754)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.flush(BufferedRecords.java:99)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:78)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:62)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:66)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:429)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:250)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:179)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have already tried to low the batch.size property, evento as low as 100 and it is still failing.

Added connector status:

```
{"name":"teradata-sink-K_C_OSUSR_DGL_DFORM_I1-V2",
"connector":{
"state":"RUNNING",
"worker_id":"10.28.148.64:41029"},
"tasks":[{"state":"FAILED","trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:451)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:250)
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:179)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)
 java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n","id":0,"worker_id":"10.28.148.64:41029"}]}
```

Comment: What is the status of your connector? `curl localhost:8083/connectors/connector-name/status | jq`

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I added it to the question

Comment: Are you sure your batch does not contain updates on the same primary keys? That can be an issue with some databases.

Comment: @MarkusRother, no, I am pretty sure because we had that issue before and it is not happening now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue while trying to write to teradata from spark using JDBC. Apparently, this happens with teradata only. It happens when you try to write to one table using multiple JDBC connections parallely. In my case, spark was forking multiple jdbc connection to teradata while writing the data to Teradata.
Your options are:

- You have to restrict your application not to make multiple jdbc
  connections, you can monitor that from Viewpoint if you have access.
- You can try providing a jdbc type=FASTLOAD and see if it is working. 
  [like this](https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#BABFGFAF)
- Or go for TPT which handles this issue internally.